# Upload file into aws bucket s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

With the root user, I created an admin user. I logged in to AWS console using the admin user. However, when I tried to upload a file into a bucket, I have received the error below:

> Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReaderSync': The requested file could not be read, typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference to a file was acquired.

[image]

Comment: That message doesn't appear to be from the web console.  The web console login is only relevant on the web console.

Comment: what is the file extension ?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to show where this message is appearing? The error appears to be related to your browser, not to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an AWS specific issues, but your local browser attempting to protect you.

Read the error list at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync/readAsArrayBuffer to see if your file falls foul of one of the following:

```
SecurityError DOMException
 - Thrown if one of the following problematic situation is detected:
    - the resource has been modified by a third party;
    - too many read are performed simultaneously;
    - the file pointed by the resource is unsafe for a use from the Web (like it is a system file).

NotReadableError DOMException
 - Thrown if the resource cannot be read due to a permission problem, like a concurrent lock.

EncodingError DOMException
 - Thrown if the resource is a data URL and exceed the limit length defined by each browser.
```

Then make the file safe for the browser to read. (e.g. check the extension/mime type matches the file contents, check no malicious code, check the file is not open in another window and locked from being read)

If that fails, and you must have that file up in that format, use AWS Cli (https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to do the upload.